# How do I add my own custom items to Firefox's in-webpage context menu?

Tags: windows-10, firefox

So basically, I have all kinds of command-line scripts which I have coded to do various things for me. One of them downloads any video from a webpage, and another figures out and opens Instagram images in their full size. So far, so good.

However, each time I want to use these tools, I have to manually copy and paste the URL from Firefox into my script and run it. This sort of defeats the point.

I wish to be able to add my own context menu item in Firefox, so that when I right-click the webpage, I get an option saying (for example) "Download the video" which, when clicked, simply runs a specificed command such as:

```
php /path/to/my/script.php --URL="%1"
```

Where %1 of course means the current webpage's URL.

I have looked long and hard, searched and asked all over, but there seems to be no way simply edit a nice little config to accomplish this. The only suggestions talk about using some scary, third-party "extension". I hate those extensions. I don't even trust Mozilla these days (and with good reason), let alone all these sketchy third-party extensions which seem to just scream "spying/malware" to me.

After all, if I just blindly could trust extensions, I could just use some extension to accomplish these tasks which I went out of my way to automate on my own.

Still, if there *really* is no way to do this without an extension, maybe you can at least suggest one that isn't all evil? I frankly think it's absolutely insane that something as simple as editing the context menu (also for removing all kinds of garbage that Mozilla has put in there which I keep selecting by accident) isn't (easily?) possible.

PS: I'm absolutely *not* interested in "developing my own extension".

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely something that would work best if developed as part of a WebExtension. The relevant API would be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/menus).

If you really don't want to go down that path, you can sort-of work around the browser's context menu by listening for [contextMenu events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event) to create your own in-page 'menu' and stop the default one from showing by cancelling that event. This is how some websites add their own custom right-click menus.